# figuring out how many rows, asymptoticly, a query is going to return in terms of x

Tags: mysql, sql, math, join

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE sample (
  id INT
);
```

Let's say I have x rows in it.

I do `SELECT COUNT(1) FROM sample` and get x back.

Now say I do this:

```
SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM sample AS s1
JOIN sample AS s2
  ON s2.id < s1.id;
```

That gets me (x*(x-1))/2 rows back.

Now say I do this:

```
SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM sample AS s1
JOIN sample AS s2
  ON s2.id < s1.id
LEFT JOIN sample AS s3
  ON s3.id < s2.id;
```

That gets me `x*(x-1)*(x-2)/6+(x-1)`. If I did a JOIN instead of a LEFT JOIN I'd be getting back `x*(x-1)*(x-2)/6` rows.

```
SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM sample AS s1
JOIN sample AS s2
  ON s2.id < s1.id
LEFT JOIN sample AS s3
  ON s3.id < s2.id
LEFT JOIN sample AS s4
  ON s4.id > s2.id
    AND s4.id < s1.id;
```

I have no idea how many rows I'd be getting back.

What the final query is intended to do, incidentally, is to give you the second id. eg.

```
SELECT s1.id
FROM sample AS s1
JOIN sample AS s2
  ON s2.id < s1.id
LEFT JOIN sample AS s3
  ON s3.id < s2.id
LEFT JOIN sample AS s4
  ON s4.id > s2.id
    AND s4.id < s1.id
WHERE s3.id IS NULL
  AND s4.id IS NULL;
```

It's more useful when the id's have users associated with them and you're trying to find the second id for a specific user or all users. I'm just trying to understand how it performs asymptotically.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: examples 2 and 3 were exponential, what makes you think that 4 and 5 are asymptotic? (because I don't think they are...)

Comment: To be honest I just used a fancy word without really knowing what it means lol. Looking it up on wikipedia I guess it's more intended to describe how comparatively trivial components of an equation are dropped with regard to big-O notation. Like example 3 would I guess by asymptotically equivalent to x**3. idk lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a not-very-mathematical way to find the polynomial you're looking for. You can use the [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/df034/4) you made to find the result for the first few numbers. Afterwards, you can use [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=polynomial%20%7B%7B2,1%7D,%20%7B3,%203%7D,%20%20%7B4,%208%7D,%20%20%7B5,%2018%7D,%20%20%7B6,%2036%7D,%20%20%7B7,%2066%7D,%20%20%7B8,%20113%7D,%20%20%7B9,%20183%7D%7D).

The result: x^4/24 - x^3/4 + 35*x^2/24 - 13*x/4 + 3.

Comment: Please note that above polynomial is for the SELECT _without_ the two WHERE ... IS NULL clauses. For large n, this is an O(n^4) Performance. As I pointed out, the actual select may very well have a O(n^4) performance but should only have a O(n^2) set of results.

Comment: Assuming the values in the table are unique I'd expect it to only have one result.

Answer (score 1):

Reading your comment about performance and big-O notation, I suddenly understand what you're after - or at least I think I do.

With *n* being the number of elements in your table, the performance of your first select is O(*n*):

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM sample  -> O(n)
```

On your second select, you are right. It gives (*n**(*n*-1))/2 rows back. Because the square part of the equation is dominant for large *n*, you can drop both the subtraction (-1) and the division (/2). The performance is O(*n*²). Going back to your SQL query, this means you can simply drop the condition in your JOIN clause. It can be simplified to:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM sample, sample   => O(n²)
```

The LEFT JOIN in your third select will have the same effect. A simple left join ON (s1.id<s2.id) will return an additional n*(-1) rows, which an INNER JOIN wouldn't. In big-O notation, that still is O(*n*²), with or without the WHERE clause. So LEFT JOIN or not, same thing. So your third select will therefore follow O(*n*³) for large *n*.

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM sample, sample, sample => O(n³)
```

Using the prior understanding, it is easy to see that your fourth SELECT comes down to

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM sample, sample, sample, sample => O(n^4)
```

It is easy to see how O() is follows the number of records and the number of self-joins of the sample table.

The only question that's left to answer is how a "WHERE rightside.id IS NULL" affects the system. By definition, a "SELECT FROM a, LEFT JOIN b where b.key IS NULL" can only return the same amount or less rows than are in table a. Thus, the select can be simplified to:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM sample, sample, const, const => O(n²)
```

Whether a database actually performs like that or whether it will build the full cartesian product and then eliminate the vast majority of rows is dependant on the implementation of the database's query optimizer, and has to be answered with regards to a specific database implementation. Worst case, the database will perform like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM sample, sample, sample, sample => O(n^4)
```

I hope this answers your question. If not, I'm sorry... but even then, I still had fun dissecting your queries :)

Comment: I was more interested in knowing the exact number of rows returned lol. Here's an sql fiddle I made: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/97e47/4 I want to know how many rows I'll get back (before the WHERE) without having to manually insert those rows.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to identify two of the same name entries or are you looking for a technical explanation on how the query runs?

I set up a [SQLfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cc746/32) for the dups and threw some rows in with one duplicate value.  It finds the duplicate value in the valu column by querying itself for the current row's value, using the count() function it will determine if there is more than one.

You can run the join queries you have if you like but I wouldn't go past two joins.  :)

Comment: That's not really what I'm looking for. So given the above schema let's say I insert 7 rows into it. The second SELECT gives me 21 rows back. ie. 7*6/2. I don't even have to run the SELECT to know how many rows it's going to give me. I just plug in the number of rows in the original table and I'll get back the count. But what are the formulas to do that for the third and fourth SELECTs? That's what I want to know.

Comment: I understand what you're after now.  Honestly, you'd probably have better luck with extracting a formula from a mathematics expert. [tag:mathematical-expressions]

Comment: I love math now, but not so much when I was in school.  I worked with one guy on a dev team that was a math professor as well.  He had formulas for everything. I wish I remembered the one he used to validate large chunks of data by looking at a few specific locations determined by the total number of locations available.